# Node/react best practice: How do I keep track on the current client/user in OAuth2 flow?

Tags: node.js, api, reactjs, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm a beginner with Node and React, and web programming in general. I want to import user credentials from LinkedIn's API and for that I need to authenticate using OAuth2.

My approach so far is to make an API-call from the client side to the LinkedIn oauth API with the relevant parameters, including a redirect URI which leads to an API endpoint on my node server. When the user has been redirected and approved LinkedIn's authentication dialog box, they will be redirected to the node server with an access token.

My question is as follows: I now want to update the user in my database with their corresponding access token, but how do I know which user to update when I can't get any information about the client in my function that handles the last redirect and fetches the access token?

Here's my node function that handles the redirect from LinkedIn:

```
router.get('/redirect', (req, res) => {

  // Handle cancel by user
  if(req.query.error){
    console.log(req.query.error_description)
    return
  }


  // Extract variables
  const code = req.query.code
  const state = req.query.state

  // Check that state matches
  if (state !== testState) {
    console.log("State doesnt match")
    return
  }

  // Exchange Authorization Code for an Access Token
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken',
    form: {
      client_id: 'theClientID',
      client_secret: 'theClienSecret',
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/linkedin/redirect'
    },
    headers:
     { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
       "content-type": "application/json",
       'user-agent': 'node.js' },
     json: true };

   // make the actual request
   request(options, (error, response, body) => {
     if (error) {
       res.status(500).json({
         message: error
       })
       return
     }

     // Extract access token
     const token =  body.access_token;

     // Here I want to save access token to DB with the corresponding
     // user, but I don't know which user to update

   })

   // Redirect user to profile
   res.writeHead(301, {
     Location: 'http://localhost:3000/profile'
   })
   res.end()
})
```

I had a really hard time formulating this question but I hope that my message gets through.

Comment: You want the client (React) to save the token and then use the token as an auth header in your api requests. Then for each request, your api can validate the token passed in the request headers.

Comment: Okay! I thought I read somewhere that you don't want the client to access the token for security reasons. But I will try your solution. Thanks! @ChaseDeAnda